# OAuth 2.0 flow using Keycloak with a back-end and front-end?

Tags: angular, rest, oauth-2.0, wildfly, keycloak

I'm working on a project that consists of:

- A back-end in Java (JEE project deployed on Wildfly)
- Front-end developed in Angular
- Keycloak for authorization and authentication

What I need to do is:

1. Access my Angular app, which communicates with my backend calling its APIs(e.g GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)
2. Go to the Login Page, authentication is done by Keycloak, so I get directed to Keycloak login
   page.
3. Login is successfull ----> I get redirected to my Angular landing page, now I can navigate my
   Angular app.

The frontend is talking with the backend via RESTful APIs, and I need to use **OAuth2.0/OPENID** standard flow, which means I'm gonna first get the auth code
and the the access token/refresh token to stay connected.

My backend is already configurated with Keycloak through the **Wildfly adapter** given on Keycloak official site, and through *web.xml* and *keycloak.json* both in **WEB-INF** folder.

So known that I'm able to get the auth code via the Valid Redirect URIs given by Keycloak, how can I configure my whole project to get the 3 points written above? Do I need two clients on my **Realm** in Keycloak?

Can someone please explain me how I can I setup the whole flow using Keycloak?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to create another client. You can name it frontend set the access type to public. Meanwhile your keycloak backend should be set to bearer only.
Follow this links to understand better

[Link1](https://medium.com/@kamleshbadgujar00/secure-spring-boot-angular-9-application-using-keycloak-2-3-bf98ba360d66)

[Link2](https://medium.com/@kamleshbadgujar00/integrating-angular-application-with-keycloak-3-3-8aee940897e)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer could be improved by quoting/citing the relevant documentation from your embedded links (link death is a real thing). Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.